# Cosa significava "imporre un taglione sulla testa" di qualcuno?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Il governo spaventò coi terrori le popolazioni, e, dileguatesi le speranze, tutto ritornò tetro come nel passato. Capi del movimento 
>   politico sono creduti e affermati lo Spinuzza, Nicolò e Carlo Botta fratelli, Andrea Maggio e Alessandro Guarnera; e il governo, a facilitare i loro arresti e i loro ammazzamenti **impone sulle loro 
>   teste un taglione**. Accresce poi la barbarie dell'agire coll'arresto delle famiglie dei fuggenti; specialmente, e con modi non consentiti dalla civiltà e dalla umanità, della famiglia Botta, arrestando le signorine Elisabetta e Giuseppina e la madre, la signora Concetta; le quali, rinchiuse in criminali, orridi e fetenti, vi rimasero parecchi mesi, trasportate di qui pure nelle prigioni di Palermo.

La mia domanda è: qual è il significato di "imporre un taglione sulla testa" di qualcuno? Significa offrire una recompensa per consegnare tale persona alle forze dell'ordine?

Alla voce "taglione" dei dizionari che ho consultato non appare questa locuzione.

Ho trovato però questa espressione in alcuni testi dell'Ottocento, per esempio:

- [*Bellezze della storia antica*](https://books.google.es/books?id=gOREQH3-uU0C&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=taglione+%22sulla+testa%22&source=bl&ots=fgd9TmqM3P&sig=6dg2ubWZF46GEIlej3Rqs5g71_8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9lfCe97_bAhVhBsAKHUpdBl8Q6AEIGzAF)
- [*L'operajo*](https://books.google.es/books?id=gAnb3_1hI9IC&pg=PA84&dq=taglione+%22sulla+testa%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwlM7597_bAhVHOMAKHZzVBH4Q6AEIETAB)
- [*La cieca di Sorrento*](https://books.google.es/books?id=kP_wzA6Db-YC&pg=PA12&dq=taglione+%22sulla+testa%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwlM7597_bAhVHOMAKHZzVBH4Q6AEIKTAG)

Comment: Credo proprio che tu abbia ragione, e significhi appunto mettere una taglia per facilitare la cattura di quelle persone.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Quindi, sarebbe il significato **4** del [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/taglia1). Interessante: non conoscevo neanche questa espressione, "mettere una taglia sulla testa di qualcuno".

Comment: Forse "taglione" sta per "grossa taglia" con questo significato.

Comment: L'autore ha semplicemente adoperato la parola sbagliata: *taglione* non significa “grossa taglia*. Succede di scivolare. In genere l'accrescitivo con cambio di genere indica una sfumatura leggermente diversa: *palla-pallone*, *donna-donnone*. Non vedo la possibilità con *taglia-taglione*, dal momento che *taglione* vuole già dire un'altra cosa.

Comment: @egreg: Ma "mettere un taglione sulla testa di ..." si trova in parecchi testi dell'Ottocento. E il linguaggio in cui è scritto il romanzo è molte volte volutamente ottocentesco.

Comment: @egreg: Poi, so che l'autore ha messo parecchi anni per elaborare il libro e si è documentato molto. Potrebbe ben essere che nei documenti che narrano la vicenda raccontata nel brano apparisse appunto il vocabolo "taglione".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mettere un taglione per arrivare alla cattura di una persona vuole dire appunto prevedere il pagamento di una grossa somma di denaro (o taglia) a vantaggio di chi riesce a portare a termine l’incarico.

Normalmente chi si occupa di dare la caccia a queste persone si definisce cacciatore di taglie.

Ovviamente promettere un premio per la cattura invoglia molte più persone e complica la latitanza del fuggitivo.

Hoepli indica la seguente accezione di [taglione](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/T/taglione_2.aspx?query=taglione%20(2)):

> Grossa taglia, balzello, tassa che si imponeva in passato per
>   provvedere a spese pubbliche straordinarie di carattere non bellico

La parola [taglione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/taglione/), con un significato diverso, compare anche nell’espressione “legge del taglione “ che ha radici molto antiche:

> Pena comune a tutti i popoli antichi, consistente nell’infliggere
>   all’autore di una lesione personale un’uguale lesione.

e conosciuta anche come legge “dell’occhio per occhio, dente per dente”

Comment: Tuttavia, etimologicamente, la "legge del taglione" (dal [latino *talio -onis*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/taglione1/)) ha qualcosa a che vedere con questo "taglione" che, se ho capito bene il commento di @RiccardoDeContardi, proviene da "taglia"?

Comment: @Charo Taglione, come hai visto da Treccani, deriva dall’infliggere lo stesso danno a chi lo ha causato. Il significato più vicino è quello di Hoepli, cioè grossa taglia.

Comment: @Charo No, *taglione* in "legge del taglione" non ha niente a che vedere con "taglia" in *mettere una taglia sulla testa di qualcuno*, eccetto che entrambi, alla lunga, derivano da *tagliare*

Comment: Quindi, come ho detto in un commento precedente, il senso sarebbe quello di "grossa taglia", in cui "taglia" avrebbe il significato **4** del [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/taglia1)?

Comment: Un'altra cosa: può essere che l'espressione che appare nel Treccani, cioè, "mettere una taglia sulla testa di qualcuno" sia oggigiorno più usata di quella che appare nella domanda, a volte in senso figurato?

Comment: @DenisNardin: So che non mi sono espressa bene, ma volevo dire che, siccome l'etimologia è diversa, non credo che la "legge del taglione" c'entri con il "taglione" della domanda.

Comment: @denisnardin Certo, hai ragione, i significati sono diversi. La mia era solo una precisazione sul fatto che taglione faceva parte di una citazione molto famosa.

Answer (score 2):

A integrazione della risposta già esistente, ecco cosa dice il Battaglia sulle varie parole “taglione”:

[image]
[image]

Quindi risulta confermato che, dato il contesto, qui ci si riferisce a una “Ricompensa promessa da uno Stato per l'uccisione o per l'aiuto alla cattura di un soggetto considerato nemico pubblico” etc. (Taglione<sup>2</sup>, 2), cioè un semplice accrescitivo di “taglia”, che a sua volta ha a che fare, attraverso il francese, con “tagliare” e con “talea”.

Invece il “taglione” forse più noto, quello della legge del taglione, il cosiddetto “occhio per occhio, dente per dente” (sul Battaglia, Taglione<sup>1</sup>) ha un diverso etimo, che *non* c'entra con “tagliare”, bensì deriva dal latino *talio*, -*onis*, forse collegato a *talis*, forse no.

Comment: Qualcuno sa se c'è modo di rimpicciolire le immagini?

Comment: L'unica cosa che mi viene in mente è trattare le immagini con un software esterno come, per esempio, il GIMP.

Comment: @Charo: Sì, posso modificare io le immagini originali, ma speravo che ci fosse qualche parametro per visualizzarle ingrandite o rimpicciolite qui. Se no, poi le modifico.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269902/allow-custom-widths-on-images-like-s-128-but-keeping-proportions

Comment: Ottimo, @Charo, grazie!